# Is there a Shoveler widget available for GWT?

Tags: gwt

I was wondering if anybody knew of an open-source Shoveler widget for GWT, [like the one the YUI library has](http://yuilibrary.com/gallery/show/shoveler). For an example, see http://gregthebusker.com/yui/shoveler/testShoveler.html

Thanks,

Lucas

Comment: Hi What exactly is a shoveler? Is it like a image slider widget? Can you give some link to the image of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is an equivalent of the Image Slider in JQuery, no there is no such widget in GWT. You may have to make your own using the basic widgets.

Comment: Not even as part of another independent GWT widget library?

Comment: Sorry I don't know of a custom GWT library that has image slider.

Comment: What you can do though is get two buttons for the left and right navigation, which will have to have a click handler, an image holder for the images. So when you click on the left and right button, the images in the middle slide's on the corresponding direction.